# No character theory, any representation ${\bf{GL}}_N(\mathbb{C})$ is reducible, upper bound

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

Let $G$ be any finite group. How do I show without character theory that there is a number $N = N(G)$ so that any representation $\rho: G \to {\bf{GL}}_N(\mathbb{C})$ is reducible (and finding an explicit upper bound for $N$)? This is trivial with characters, I just don't see how to do it without. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If $N \ge 1 + |G|$, let $x \in \mathbb{C}^N - \{0\}$. Let $V$ be the vector space spanned by $\{\rho(s)x\text{ }|\text{ }s \in G\}$. Then $V$ is a nonzero sub-$G$-module of $\mathbb{C}^N$ and $\dim(V) \le |G| \le N-1$, so $V \neq \mathbb{C}^N$. Hence $\rho$ is reducible.